# what is the difference between stl priority_queue and heap-related method?

Tags: c++, stl

I used heap-related operations to maintain a `heap` structure.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1,2,56, 2};
std::make_heap(a.begin(), a.end());
// add
a.push_back(3);
std::push_heap(a.begin(), a.end());
// erase
std::pop_heap(a.begin(), a.end());
int v = a.back();
a.pop_back();
```

Recently, I find there is a structure named `priority_queue` seems also implement a heap.

which has simpler function with `push` `pop`.

Is there any difference between these two? (performance, memory, and other things)

And which one you think is better?

can i use `reserve` to reduce memory allocate time since the container is vector (for heap operation)?

Comment: *"And which one you think is better?"* -- you should remove this part of the question as without objective criteria for "better", it is opinion-based. Plus, one question per question.

Comment: *"can i use reserve to [...]"* -- given Stack Overflow's prohibition against multiple questions in a question, I suggest removing this from your question. But before you post a new question for this, take a look at [priority_queue underlying vector container capacity resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666387/c-priority-queue-underlying-vector-container-capacity-resize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> Working with a `priority_queue` is similar to managing a [heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) in some random access container, with the benefit of not being able to accidentally invalidate the heap.

And in case it isn't clear: your code manages a heap in a random access container.